# Binding Events to AJAX added elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I know that this question has been asked before,but unfortunately those didn't seem to solve my issue.
I have a `<table>` and i have to add `dblclick` event to each of those,but i also am adding rows to the table using AJAX(after page load).

I have got it working but have posted 2 codes,one worked and other didn't.

a)This code works for me:

```
$(document).on("dblclick","td",function(){ 
   //THIS WORKS FOR ELEMNTS ADDED AFTER PAGE LOAD
});
```

b)This code i tried earlier that didn't work:

```
$("td").on("dblclick","td",function(){ 
   //THIS DIDN'T FOR ELEMNTS ADDED AFTER PAGE LOAD

});
```

Even tried adding a class to newly added `<td>` and passed it in the second parameter,but it didn't seem to work.

Anyone please explain,whats the problem in the second case.?

Comment: very related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Anyone please explain,whats the problem in the second case.?

You are saying *"Even tried adding a class to newly added `<td>`"* which implies that you are creating new `<td>` elements.

The event handler has to be bound to an **existing, "static" ancestor** of the elements that are dynamic.

Your handler, `$("td").on("dblclick","td",function() {})` doesn't make much sense. It would listen to clicks on table cells *inside* other table cells.

Have a look at the jQuery tutorial [Understanding Event Delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) to learn more about event delegation.

Comment: But the second parameter is for elements that will be added in the future right?

Comment: Yes.... that's why it doesn't make a lot of sense to use the same selector in both cases.

Comment: King So had i used to bind it to `<tbody>` and used `$("tbody").on("dblclick","td",function() {})` ,it would have worked?

Comment: @varun: Yes, on every single <td> inside a <tbody>.

Comment: @FelixKling Thanks mate, i guess existing ancestor was the thing i was missing

Comment: @briosheje Thanks mate! I guess ancestor was the concept i was missing.